# converting JSON string into a python dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, json, dictionary

I have been tasked to create a JSON string which I then need to convert into a python dictionary.

I am just getting errors about extra data and I am unsure what to do next

```
import json

company = '{"Name": "George", "Manages": ["James", "Jamilia"]}, {"Name": "James", "Manages": ["Jill", "Jenny"]}, {"Name": "Jamilia", "Manages": ["Jasmine", "Jewel", "Jenny"]}'

company_dict = json.loads(company)
```

The task I am trying to complete is the following question: George runs a company. He manages James and Jamila, who each have a small team to manage. In James' team are Jill and Jenny. In Jamila's team are Jewel, Jasmine and Jeremy.

Create a JSON object in a string variable called company where each item has a name field and a field called manages which contains an array of the people managed by that person. If a person does not manage anybody, they have no field called manages.

Then convert the JSON string to a dictionary in a variable called company_dict.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON, as you have several objects separated by commas but they aren't in an array. Should they be?

Comment: No, I want the initial part to be valid JSON - and then to convert that into a python dict.

Comment: If you have several items,  they either need to be in an array or another object (associated with keys, obviously). See json.org for what constitutes valid JSON.

Comment: Still can't work it out, I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm not sure what to tell you. You can't have valid JSON for several items not in an array or an object. That's all there is to it, really.

Answer (score 1):

> ... each item has a name field and a field called manages which contains an array of the people managed by that person. If a person does not manage anybody, they have no field called manages.

That sounds like an organization tree.  Each employee has a name and optionally who they manage:

```py
import json
from pprint import pprint

company = '''{"name": "George",
              "manages": [{"name": "James",
                           "manages": [{"name": "Jill"},
                                       {"name": "Jenny"}]},
                          {"name": "Jamila",
                           "manages": [{"name": "Jewel"},
                                       {"name": "Jasmine"},
                                       {"name": "Jeremy"}]}]}'''

dct = json.loads(company)
pprint(dct, sort_dicts=False)
print()
print(json.dumps(dct, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{'name': 'George',
 'manages': [{'name': 'James',
              'manages': [{'name': 'Jill'}, {'name': 'Jenny'}]},
             {'name': 'Jamila',
              'manages': [{'name': 'Jewel'},
                          {'name': 'Jasmine'},
                          {'name': 'Jeremy'}]}]}

{
  "name": "George",
  "manages": [
    {
      "name": "James",
      "manages": [
        {
          "name": "Jill"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jenny"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Jamila",
      "manages": [
        {
          "name": "Jewel"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jasmine"
        },
        {
          "name": "Jeremy"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```